# Input validation for mm:ss

Tags: html, validation

I want to allow input text filed to enter only in format of "mm:ss".

mm : will be 00 to 99

ss : will be 00 to 59

It should allow two char before ":" and two char after ":" and not allow to enter any more char in input box.

waiting for replay...

Thanks in advance

Comment: please share a fiddle and show your attempts

Comment: @krunal: you can do some research, SO already has answers for this.

Comment: @Nadeem Khan I am using http://jsfiddle.net/4p5gxn2n/ , but it allow to enter more char.

Comment: @Krunal; You want it in HTML ?

Comment: Please do not use the jQuery Validate tag when the question contains nothing about this plugin.

Comment: @Sparky: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically for validatiing in `mm:ss` you have to be just concentrating on the time of **60** seconds.
See the proper fiddle and use it accordingly

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fncwbgjq/9/)

Comment: I want to disallow to enter other char. For example if 99:80 then it should not allow to enter 5th char as 99:801

Comment: @Krunal: Yes it is disallowing the fifth character. Please check properly.http://jsfiddle.net/fncwbgjq/4/

Comment: @Krunal: Did it worked or not ? or share some more thing what exactly you want.

Comment: Like in maxLength If we set it to 4, we are not enable to enter 5th char like that i need..

Comment: @Krunal: See the updated link and please mark it correct if it helped you. Thanks. Do let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: pls check this link http://jsfiddle.net/fncwbgjq/11/ it is not allow to enter 6th char

Comment: I m still confused what you exactly want, I have given you solution for the validation of `mm:ss`and it is working also it is not allowing to enter the 6th char. See this http://jsfiddle.net/fncwbgjq/9/

Comment: Yes jsfiddle.net/fncwbgjq/9 this is right but it should 2 char before ":" and 2 char after ":" are only allow.

Comment: @Krunal; check the working demo link, that was same.